# Squid proxy limit

Tags: proxy, squid

My college uses squid 2.6 stable for limiting access and speed of internet.

Some of the problems are --

1) Chrome gives access denied for almost every other site I visit, though these are on whitelist.

2) My speed is limited to 25kbps even late in the night when no one uses internet.

Comment: just as a side info, which college are you from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's truly Chrome that's giving the denial (not Squid) then try a different browser.  If it's Squid (you should see a message that says squid is blocking the site) then take it up with the squid admins.  It could be a simple configuration problem that they can fix.

Just because a site is whitelisted doesn't mean squid will like every page on it.  Squid can be configured to do keyword blocking as well as IP blocking (black/white lists).  The order in which the filters are applied can also be the source of "interesting" behavior.

As to the 25 kb/s limit - you do mean 25 k-bytes/s don't you?  My last phone modem was 48 kbits/sec and even that would be totally unusable with most of todays websites.

Comment: i am on firefox for this reason. When is say it blocks the ones on whitelist i mean even google and yahoo main pages randomly.